# access denied for MMS connection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata-service

When I select the connection for the default managed metadata service application (Managed Metadata Service) and click properties it generates: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. I checked ULS logs I found: Exception returned from back end service. System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

(the current user is Administrator and has been added to managed metadata service application permissions.
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Is the Managed Metadata running on the same server as the Web Front end? If not are you running Kerberos?

Comment: Yes, Managed Metadata running on Web front end. and I am running Kerberos.